# SpEL: get current bean name during bean instantiation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-el

I am attempting to use SpEL to get the name of the bean currently being instantiated to allow multiple beans of same class to be created with different properties supplied by `@PropertySource`. I am hoping for something like the following:

```
public class SampleBean {
    @Value("${#{CurrentBeanName}.val}")
    private String val
}
```

Other bean:

```
public class OtherBean {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(name="BeanA")
    SampleBean beanA;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(name="BeanB")
    SampleBean beanB;
}
```

properties file:

```
BeanA.val=VALUE A
BeanB.val=VALUE B
```

If I add `beanName=BeanA` to my properties file, I am able to get this to work with

```
@Value("${${beanName}.val}")
```

Any ideas on what to do for `#{BeanName}`? If this is impossible then so be it, but if it works it would be much cleaner than my current solution.

EDIT:

Or any way to pass a constant from the xml bean definition to SpEL? example:

```
<bean id="BeanA" class="...">
    <property name="prefix" value="BeanA"/>
</bean>
```

java:

```
public class SampleBean {
    @Value("${#{prefix}.val}")
    private String val
}
```

Any sort of attribute or anything would work

EDIT2:

This is trivial in old XML based config

spring.xml:

```
<bean id="beanA" class="SampleBean">
    <property name="val" value="${BeanA.val}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="beanB" class="SampleBean">
    <property name="val" value="${BeanB.val}"/>
</bean>
```

SampleBean.java:

```
public class SampleBean {

    private String val;

    public void setVal (String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

However when switching to the new `@Value` annotations to get rid of all the setters, it seems non-singletons with diff properties aren't supported (i.e. no way to dynamically filter `@Value` arguments on bean creation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; it is not possible to reference the current bean.

**EDIT**

To address your comment below, the Java Configuration equivalent of

```
<bean id="BeanA" class="com.my.Foo">
    <property name="prefix" value="BeanA"/>
</bean>
```

is

```
@Bean
public Foo BeanA() {
    Foo a = new Foo();
    a.setPrefix("BeanA");
}
```

although, by convention, you'd probably name it `beanA`.

Comment: is there any way at all to pass any form of "argument" from the xml definition to where SpEL does its substitutions?

Comment: No; if you are doing that, then why not just add a setter for `val` and use `<property name="val" value="BeanA.val" />` ?

Comment: That is my current solution. There are a rather large amount of properties that need to be set though. The setters become unwieldy (and are ugly) and currently I have no configs defined in my xml. Making sure the `properties` list in `BeanA`, `BeanB`, etc. match is also quite error prone compared to `@Value` which throws an exception if the placeholders cannot be resolved (i.e. I forgot a config).

In short, I was just looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: just seems odd to me that something so simple and useful from the old XML based configurations would not have been addressed during the development of the newer annotation driven configuration.

Comment: is this something that is possible with a java Configuration class?

Comment: `>old XML based configurations would not have been addressed during the development of the newer annotation`. I don't follow - edit your question to show exactly what you can do with XML that you can't do with Java Configuration. Using `@Value` is very different to `@Bean`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have singleton bean types you could just use a `static final` variable for the name and then reference that. But the bigger issue is that you will be breaking the `Spring` inversion of control principals if you begin depending on `Spring` bean names, which is why this sort of thing isn't done. Pretty much want to focus on creating modules and domains for your project. If you begin accessing components coming from the Spring Context directly (such as the bean name) you will find that your modules will become brittle, hard to change and very hard to reason about as they begin to depend on behaviour from seemingly unrelated modules, such as the Spring Dependency Injection Framework. Although you may have a valid use-case for doing this you just need to be very very careful.

Comment: the beans I am attempting to do this for are not singletons. The behaviour I am trying to duplicate was easily accomplished with xml and setters, but seems to be unsupported by newer annotation-based configuration.

Comment: I don't follow - edit your question to show exactly what you can do with XML that you can't do with Java Configuration. Using `@Value` is very different to `@Bean`.

Comment: You may have a requirement for having GUIDs maybe for logging or what not. But you really shouldn't need to know the names of beans except for using the `@Qualifier` annotation, I suggest you describe more about what you are wanting to do. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem