# @Bean annotation name attribute value to take from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I want to read `@Bean` annotations `name` attribute value from properties file, something like below.

Properties File:
`myBeanName : abc`

In java code I want to achieve as below,
`@Bean(name = "${myBeanName}")`
Which should be equal to
`@Bean(name = "abc")`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431658/spel-get-current-bean-name-during-bean-instantiation

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is the *actual issue* you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want define one property for bean name, and want to use that property while defining bean and also in ```@Qualifier``` while autowiring

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.html

But I think your actual problem has easier solution